# Does Roslyn care for syntactic correctness. If so how to turn it on?

Tags: c#, roslyn

I wanted to find out lines of code using Roslyn from C#. Here is what I tried.

```
SyntaxTree tree = SyntaxTree.ParseText(@"int fun(int x){ int y = 0; x++; return x+1; return z;} 
                                                 double funny(double x){ return x/2.13;}");

List<MethodDeclarationSyntax> methods = tree.GetRoot()
    .DescendantNodes()
    .Where(d => d.Kind == SyntaxKind.MethodDeclaration)
    .Cast<MethodDeclarationSyntax>()
    .ToList();
int lvc = methods[0].Body.Statements
    .Count(x => x.Kind == SyntaxKind.LocalDeclarationStatement);
methods.Select(z => new { MethodName = z.Identifier.ValueText, LoC = z.Body.Statements.Count })
    .OrderByDescending(x => x.LoC)
    .ToList()
    .ForEach(x => Console.WriteLine(x.MethodName + " " + x.LoC));
```

and I got the following output

> fun 4
>
> funny 1

But I have two return statements in the function `fun`. That code won't compile in real settings. How to make these sort of mistakes disappear while using Roslyn?

Comment: Yes; you need to actually tell it to run the compiler, by creating a `Compilation`.

Answer (score 5):

It *does* compile in normal settings. It just gives a warning:

> Unreachable code detected

There is nothing wrong with Roslyn.

Comment: `return z;` - will it compile in real life? The variable is undefined, no?

Comment: @UlugbekUmirov This most likely is an error in the question itself, because the OP wanted to show a simplified example of his real code.

Comment: Yes. I forgot to declare "z" that's a mistake / typo in my question. But Patrick if we want to find out UnReachable code using Roslyn how to do that? and also why Roslyn won't catch undeclared variables as @UlugbekUmirov pointed out. Is there a setting that I can turn on to make it look for these sort of glitches in the code?

Answer (score 1):

When you type code, your code is more often than not invalid code. What you see when you get the semantic model is basically a snapshot of the code at that point in time which gets its affected syntaxtree branches updated constantly.

You can find out whether or not you are in an uncompilable code situation by checking the diagnostics and looking whether any of them have a severity of `DiagnosticSeverity.Error`.

[Consider the following code](https://joshvarty.wordpress.com/2014/10/30/learn-roslyn-now-part-7-introducing-the-semantic-model/):

```
var tree = CSharpSyntaxTree.ParseText(@"
    public class MyClass 
    {
        int MyMethod() { return 0; }
    }");

var Mscorlib = PortableExecutableReference.CreateFromAssembly(typeof(object).Assembly);
var compilation = CSharpCompilation.Create("MyCompilation",
    syntaxTrees: new[] { tree }, references: new[] { Mscorlib });
```

You can now get all diagnostics using `compilation.GetDiagnostics();`.

Comment: Semantic model? I don't see that in the code in the question.